# exporting to csv on apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

When exporting Apache Superset charts to csv, in content of csv Latin fonts not appearing properly, on my computer side? I am opening it via Office 365.
Latin fonts not appearing properly.

I am already controlled my docker container side , core.py and supersetconfig.py in there UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with office 365 is better not opening the csv file and use the
[import csv option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4K5P.png)

Or you could try different encoding when you import it.